# Why at set checked value in input with ternary operation this return true?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I try to use this code does not work correctly:

```
document.querySelector('#myInput').checked = false == 'false' ? false : true; // This set true
```

But this code works:

```
var checkedBoolean = false == 'false' ? false : true; // return false
document.querySelector('#myInput').checked = checkedBoolean; // set true
```

why?, Thank you, it's out of curiosity..

Comment: ** correction for comment in second code:
document.querySelector('#myInput').checked = checkedBoolean; // set false

Comment: `false == 'false'` will always returns `false`, which turns to `true` in your ternary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is always `true` because `false` is never equal to `'false'` so it will return `true` every time. Even when I test it, it returns true every time (even with the `checkedBoolean`.

```html
<button id="button1">With Variable</button>
<button id="button2">Without Variable</button>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false == 'false' ? false : true;  //returns true
    var checkedBoolean = false == 'false' ? false : true;  
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = checkedBoolean;  //returns true
}
</script>
```

Hit the Run button to see the result.